# How to publish a library project on maven?

Tags: android, maven, open-source, repository, maven-central

Plain and simple.

I have an open-source library repository on GitHub and the users of this Android library are demanding that the library is published on **maven central** for easier use.  Since I am not very familiar with maven I do not really know what to do. I am also unaware what maven actually does differently then let's say Gradle and what it's advantage is.

How can I add maven support for my project? How can I upload my project to maven central?
Is there some kind of detailed tutorial on what exactly I need to do?

Comment: [This](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/09/publish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html) might help you.

Comment: @neikhaarmam that's much easier: http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get to Maven Central with Gradle is by using Bintray. Here is how: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/